# Scraping StackOverflow's questions with Node.js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, ecmascript-6, stackexchange

I'm new to node and web scraping in general but with some research I've written this working code.

My goal is to get all questions from X Stack Overflow's pages sorted by most rated and save that data locally to use on another project to plot charts and other analytical stuff.

How can I improve it in both readability and perfomance?
Any convention or language/technology nuance that I got wrong?

```
const CHEERIO = require('cheerio');
const REQUEST = require('request');
const JSONFRAME = require('jsonframe-cheerio');
const CORES = require('os').cpus().length;
const CLUSTER = require('cluster');
const FS = require('fs');
const LAST_PAGE_TO_SCRAPE = 10;
const QUANTITY_OF_PAGES_PER_WORKER = 1;

const BASE_URL = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=';
const URL_ORDERING = '&sort=votes';

if (CLUSTER.isMaster) {
    let nextPage = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < CORES; i++) {
        CLUSTER.fork({ startingPoint: nextPage });
        nextPage += 1;
    }

    CLUSTER.on('online', (worker) => {
        console.log(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} is now working.`);
    });

    CLUSTER.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        if (code !== 0) {//restart
            console.log(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} died. Restarting.`);
            CLUSTER.fork({ startingPoint: worker.process.env.startingPoint });
        } else {//scrape next X pages
            console.log(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} finished it's work succesfully.`);
            if (nextPage <= LAST_PAGE_TO_SCRAPE) {
                CLUSTER.fork({ startingPoint: nextPage });
                nextPage += QUANTITY_OF_PAGES_PER_WORKER;
            }
        }
    });
} else {
    let workerStartingPoint = parseInt(process.env.startingPoint);
    for (let i = workerStartingPoint; i < workerStartingPoint + QUANTITY_OF_PAGES_PER_WORKER; i++) {
        REQUEST(BASE_URL + i + URL_ORDERING, function (error, response, html) {
            if (error) {
                process.exit(workerStartingPoint);//error code is where the worker should start again
            }
            let $ = CHEERIO.load(html);
            JSONFRAME($);
            let frame = {
                questions: {
                    _s: "#questions .question-summary",
                    _d: [{
                        "votes": ".statscontainer .stats .vote .votes .vote-count-post strong",
                        "answers": ".statscontainer .stats .status strong",
                        "views": ".statscontainer .views",
                        "title": ".summary h3 a",
                        "tags": [".summary .tags a"],
                        "url": ".question-hyperlink @ href",
                        "user": {
                            "name": ".summary .started .user-info .user-details a",
                            "profile-link": ".summary .started .user-info .user-details a @ href",
                            "reputation": ".summary .started .user-info .user-details .-flair .reputation-score"
                        },
                        "date asked": ".summary .started .user-info .user-action-time .relativetime"
                    }]
                }
            }
            let questions = $('body').scrape(frame, { string: true });
            FS.writeFile('page-' + i + '.json', questions, function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    process.exit(workerStartingPoint);
                }
                process.exit(0);
            })
        });
    }
}
```

If you're going to run this,don't set the `LAST_PAGE_TO_SCRAPE` too large because your IP is going to get temporarily blocked by SO.

Comment: Stack Exchange has [an API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs). It may be faster than web scraping, considering you could just construct a request for whatever you'd want. That being said, I don't know how hard it is to get an API key, and writing a web scraper is a fun learning experience.

Comment: Oh,thanks a lot for that! I'll use it to earn experience working with API's but the main idea of this was to train writing web scraper.